# Delete any whitespace between two character strings in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file such as this

```
word 1334 1234
word word 32423 23423
word 213 234
word word 32423 234234
word 23423 123423
```

i would like it to be like this but disregard the periods

```
word............1334.......1234
word_word.......32423......23423
word............213........234
word_word.......32423......234234
word............23423......123423
```

On the last line, i would like to delete the white space and make it into either `wordword` or `word_word` in shell script.  I'm having problems using `column`, `grep`, and `awk`.  I think I should save it into a new file by converting all white spaces 
into `word_word` and then using `column -t -s " "` to make equal spaces.

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Could you edit the question to include a sample of your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that your question means "how do I force this data to three columns by removing any whitespace between words in columns other than the last two", I would propose

```
awk '{ f=""; for (i=1; i<=NF-2; ++i) { f=f $i; $i=""; } $1=f; print }' file
```

However, your last line only contains two columns, so this will produce aberrant output for that.

```
$ awk '{ f=""; for (i=1; i<=NF-2; ++i) { f=f $i; $i=""; } $1=f; print }' <<'HERE'
> word 1334 1234
> word word 32423 23423
> word 213 234
> word word 32423 234234
> word 123423
> HERE
word 1334 1234
wordword  32423 23423
word 213 234
wordword  32423 234234
 123423
```

You can insert a literal underscore if you like; `f=f "_" $i`

Comment: thank you tripleee, i'm trying to figure out why i can only use awk once on a .sh in vim.  i'm using your script and then using      column -t -s "    "

Comment: is awk more powerful then grep?

Comment: Can also use gensub if you have gawk `awk '{$0=gensub(/([[:alpha:]]+) ([[:alpha:]]+)/,"\\1_\\2","g")}1' file`

Comment: Yes, Awk is a programming language, so significantly more powerful than `grep`.